# How to set cache directory in knitr

Tags: r, caching, knitr

I am trying to figure out how to change the cache directory for knitr. I already tested some approaches:

---

````
```{r setup, echo = FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(png)
library(grid)
library(tufte)
library(ggplot2)
library(xtable)
opts_chunk$set(cache.path("../.intermediates"))
````

Gives me:

```
Error in cache.path("../.intermediates") :  não foi possível encontrar a função "cache.path"
```

---

````
```{r setup, echo = FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(png)
library(grid)
library(tufte)
library(ggplot2)
library(xtable)

knitr::cache.path("../.intermediates")
```
````

Results in:

```
Erro: 'cache.path' is not an exported object from 'namespace:knitr'
```

---

Using the yaml:

```
link-citations: true
lang: pt-BR
csl: chicago-fullnote-bibliography.csl
links-as-notes: yes
header-includes: |
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
knit: cache.path("../.intermediates")
```

Results in:

```
1: In file.rename(from, to) :
  não foi possível renomear o arquivo '/home/luis/Dropbox/Documentos/Psiquiatria/Projetos/LIVRO-stats/reports/stats_files/figure-latex' para '/home/luis/Dropbox/Documentos/Psiquiatria/Projetos/LIVRO-stats/.intermediates//home/luis/Dropbox/Documentos/Psiquiatria/Projetos/LIVRO-stats/reports/stats_files/figure-latex', motivo 'Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado'
2: In file.rename(from, to) :
  não foi possível renomear o arquivo '/home/luis/Dropbox/Documentos/Psiquiatria/Projetos/LIVRO-stats/.intermediates//home/luis/Dropbox/Documentos/Psiquiatria/Projetos/LIVRO-stats/reports/stats_files/figure-latex' para '/home/luis/Dropbox/Documentos/Psiquiatria/Projetos/LIVRO-stats/reports/stats_files/figure-latex', motivo 'Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado'
```

---

- What is the proper way of setting the cache directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache.path = " ")
```